# Video Mixing Renderer-9's limit of framerate

Tags: directshow

What is the highest framerate supported by VMR9 renderer? Is there any other renderer which can play high framerate videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frame rate is limited by hardware, not but the renderer implementation. All stock renderers (`VMR-7`, `VMR-9`, `EVR`) are capable of presenting high FPS video feeds.

Comment: If my monitors refresh rate is 60 Hz, will my play back be at the maximum rate of 60 frames/sec? In this case does VMR miss any frames?

Comment: VMR does not necessarily synchronize with monitor rate. It can present images faster, if the actual hardware is unable to show more than certain amount of frames per second then the "bottleneck" is on hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen systems where video renderers are limited to the monitor refresh rate of 60Hz for example and slow down the rest of the graph. This behaviour may be hardware and renderer dependent.

You may need to add some sort of frame rate limiting to discard excessive video samples if this is a problem for you. We have a small bit of custom filter code that does this to prevent VMR preview holding up other parts of the graph.